# how to find a dictionary value in django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a dictionary.

```
{21: [<Trade: SPY   190204C00271000>], 20: [<Trade: SPY   190201P00265000>]}
```

I wrote a filter to get the value from dict in Django template.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def tradeItem(inputs, i):
    return inputs.get(i)
```

in the template:

```
{{ openTrades|tradeItem:trade.trade_number }}
```

Now I am able to get this specific trade. but I need to get value of trade.price. how do i do that? I tried.

```
{{ openTrades.price|tradeItem:trade.trade_number }}
{{ (openTrades|tradeItem:trade.trade_number).price }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just extend your filter to get the price attribute instead of the trade object, eg

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def tradeItemPrice(trades, i):
    return trades.get(i).price
```

then in the template

```
{{ openTrades|tradeItemPrice:trade.trade_number }}
```

Comment: that works.  but I have 20+ attributes in that trade object. do I have to create 20 filters or there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You could instead write a custom template tag (instead of a filter) that can take mulitple arguments `(trades, i, attribute)`, then in the tag do `return getattr(trades.get(i), attribute)`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Comment: thank you so much, i got it working.   I have to create 2 filters and chain them together to get it working.